# what is the simplest way to choose a random item from 6 variables with lists

Tags: python, variables

to make my question much more simplier
i want to choose 1 random item from these 6 lists
hence a random number which includes all theses items in the list. i dont want to put them in 1 long list, due to additional and further code

```
items_1 = ["soap","ketchup","pineapple","crisp","twix"]
items_2  = ["olives","mouse pad","shampoo","coke","ruler","pen"]
items_3 =  ["honey","mirror","chocolate bar","fanta"]
items_4 = ["candle","doughnuts","pencil","dr pepper","broccoli","cabbage"]
items_5 = ["book","butter","jam","umbrella","toolbox","knife"]
items_6 = [ "tissue","iphone case","jewels","sprite"]
```

Comment: pick a list, then pick an item from the list.

Comment: i want the  item to be picked by acknowledging all the lists

Comment: as i know how to due pick a item from 1 list i want to want 1 random item from any of the list, if that is possible

Comment: ... choose a list randomly, choose an item form that list randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the lists in a list and then call [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice) twice:

```
>>> import random
>>> items_1 = ["soap","ketchup","pineapple","crisp","twix"]
>>> items_2  = ["olives","mouse pad","shampoo","coke","ruler","pen"]
>>> items_3 =  ["honey","mirror","chocolate bar","fanta"]
>>> items_4 = ["candle","doughnuts","pencil","dr pepper","broccoli","cabbage"]
>>> items_5 = ["book","butter","jam","umbrella","toolbox","knife"]
>>> items_6 = [ "tissue","iphone case","jewels","sprite"]
>>> list_of_lists = [items_1, items_2, items_3, items_4, items_5, items_6]
>>> random.choice(random.choice(list_of_lists))
'toolbox'
>>> random.choice(random.choice(list_of_lists))
'mirror'
```

The inner call randomly selects a list, and the outer call randomly selects an element.

Alternatively, you can concat all the lists to a single list and then call `randon.choice` once, but it is safe to assume that it will have a slightly worse performance.

Comment: thank you! a very great help. i guess i always need to remember if you use too many arguments you can simplify them into one variable correlating to one argument

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
n = random.randint(0, 2)
n1= random.randint(0,2)
item1 = ["blue", "yellow", "brown"]
item2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
v = (item1, item2)
print(v[n][n1])
```

hope help